# Build complex string with comment characters in an array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, drupal, comments

I have to add a dynamic snippet of JavaScript code to multiple pages based on the page name in Drupal. Below is an example of the snippet. I made notes where the data will change in the snippet of code. **MY QUESTION:** In the snippets how will I add the php variables where there are HTML comment characters?

JavaScript Code:

```
<!--
Activity name of this tag: Kids Product Page **THIS DATA WILL CHANGE****
URL of the webpage where the tag is expected to be placed: http://www.mywebsite.com/thepage/goeshere.php  **THIS DATA WILL CHANGE****
This tag must be placed between the <body> and </body> tags, as close as possible to the opening tag.
Creation Date: 09/05/2013   **THIS DATA WILL CHANGE****
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var axel = Math.random() + "";
var a = axel * 10000000000000;
document.write('<iframe src="https://website.net/activityi;src=2584392;type=2013s677;cat=vitam148;ord=1;num=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');  **THIS DATA WILL CHANGE****
</script>
<noscript>
<iframe src="https://website.net/activityi;src=2584392;type=2013s677;cat=vitam148;ord=1;num=1?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>  **THIS DATA WILL CHANGE****
</noscript>

<!-- End of JS Code: Please do not remove -->
```

I have about 20 snippets of this code I was thinking of creating a complex array but with the comment characters above I am not sure if I can place the php varaibles inside of them and it still be a comment.

Array:

```
$myData = array(
"kid_page" => array(
"page_name" => "Kids Product Page",
"page_url" => "http://www.mywebsite.com/thepage/goeshere.php",
"create_date" => "09/05/2013",
"docwrite" => '<iframe src="https://website.net/activityi;src=2584392;type=2013s677;cat=vitam148;ord=1;num=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>', 
"noscript" => '<iframe src="https://website.net/activityi;src=2584392;type=2013s677;cat=vitam148;ord=1;num=1?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>'),

"adult_page" => array(
"page_name" => "Adult Product Page",
"page_url" => "http://www.mywebsite.com/thepage/goeshere.php",
"create_date" => "10/06/2013",
"docwrite" => '<iframe src="https://website.net/activityi;src=2584392;type=2013s677;cat=vitam148;ord=1;num=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>', 
"noscript" => '<iframe src="https://website.net/activityi;src=2584392;type=2013s677;cat=vitam148;ord=1;num=1?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed php into html comments the same as you would anywhere else, using

```
<?php ?>


<!--
    Activity name of this tag: <?php echo $myData['kid_page']['page_name']; ?>
-->
```